# how to get asp.net gridview hidden field of selected value using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, hidden-field, selectedvalue

i have hidden field value inside a grid view i bound it with a linq query 
i want to get selected field value through asp:link button
my asp.net code is :

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="EditCol">EDIT</asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <input id="Hidden1" runat="server" type="hidden" visible="true" class="H" value='<%# Bind("MBody") %>' />                              
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

when i want to get selected row value using this jquery code :

```
$(document).on("click", "[id*=EditButton]", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var body = $("[id*=Hidden1]").val();
alert(body);
}
```

it just exhibits the first bounding field value not selected value
could you please help me to overcome this issue ?

Comment: may you need to inspect element using fire bug to know the id name in the Dom

Comment: i can access control dude however it just shows the value of first row of grid view!!

Comment: how you know the selected row in gridview

Comment: i dont get u! what do you mean?